# Using core data and fetch request to update a piece of data

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, ios7, nsfetchrequest

I have 2 tables like so in SQLlite:

```
Users
user_id (pk)
email
inGroups (many to many relationship with groups)

Groups
group_id (pk)
group_name
isActive
whoseUsers (many to many relationship with users)
```

I have my core data code as so:

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Users"];
request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"user_id = %@ AND ANY inGroups.group_id = %@", user, group];

NSArray *results = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

if ([results count] > 0)
{
    for (id u in results)
    {
        [u setIsActive:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1]];
    }

    if (![context save:&error2])
    {
        NSLog(@"Error couldn't save: %@", [error2 localizedDescription]);
    }
}
```

How do I set the isActive flag in Groups when I get a User back?

```
Users.h

@class Groups;

@interface Users : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * user_id;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * email;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * username;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet *inGroups;
@end

@interface Users (CoreDataGeneratedAccessors)

- (void)addInGroupsObject:(Groups *)value;
- (void)removeInGroupsObject:(Groups *)value;
- (void)addInGroups:(NSSet *)values;
- (void)removeInGroups:(NSSet *)values;


Groups.h

@class Users;

@interface Groups : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * group_id;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * isActive;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * group_name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet *whoseUsers;
@end

@interface Groups (CoreDataGeneratedAccessors)

- (void)addWhoseUsersObject:(Users *)value;
- (void)removeWhoseUsersObject:(Users *)value;
- (void)addWhoseUsers:(NSSet *)values;
- (void)removeWhoseUsers:(NSSet *)values;

@end

@end
```

Comment: Have you looked at these pages in the documentation? https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdTechnologyOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009296-SW4

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdFAQ.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001802-SW2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access mutual relations with their properties, similar to this:
(I haven't checked it, so the sintaxis might not be correct, but the idea is the same).

```
if ([results count] > 0)
{
    for (Users *user in results)
    {
        for (Groups *group in user.inGroups)
            group.isActive = [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES];
    }

    if (![context save:&error2])
    {
        NSLog(@"Error couldn't save: %@", [error2 localizedDescription]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems correct but I keep getting a: property 'inGroups' cannot be found in forward class object 'Users'

Comment: rebuild your object models, that is, delete the Users and Groups classes and then select the model, go to editor, create NSmanagedobjectsubclass

Comment: Did that, they exist in my User.h/m and Groups.h/m correctly and inGroups is an NSSet

Comment: Could you post your .h of user and that of groups?

Comment: ``#include "Users.h"``

Comment: @chris haha, well yeah, are you including the header file for your managed object subclass Users & Groups wherever you are using this code?

Comment: It wasn't imported in my category header. Thanks guys!